# wget - How to automate a wget call

Tags: automation, wget

Good Day

I am using wget to download files from a constant source.

```
$ wget --user=david --password='myPassword' http://the_url.updatedfile.pdf
```

Now these files are continuously updated, so I have to automate the download process to run say every day at 12:00

How do I achieve this? Or is the only solution to this to write a batch file containing the wget command, and then a schedules task on it?

Thank you

Comment: what operating system are you using? if you are using a *nix environment, you could write a bash script that get executed as a cron job. If in Windows, you could use a scheduled task to do this similar task.

Comment: yes windows...as I said in my question - Is a scheduled task the only way to automate this or does wget have automation built in?

Comment: wget has no automation that I know of (from a timing perspective)